# Hailstone: loop for #1-#200

Tags: java

The hailstone problem involves taking x and if it is even, divide it by two. And if it is odd, multiply it by 3 and add 1. continue this and you will get a repeating 4, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1... 
I am having trouble making a loop and having it print the solutions to the inputs #1-#200.

I tried to add a for loop, while loop, and a while loop inside of a for loop. I can't figure out how to get the variable to increase after running through the equation once.

I figured out how to do the code with an input. But here I tried to put in a for loop, but it prints "1, " and thats it.

```
for (int i = 200; i <= 200; i--) {
    System.out.print(i + ", ");

    while (i > 4) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            int i1 = i / 2;
            System.out.print(i1 + ", ");
            i = i1;
        }
        else {
            int i1 = i * 3 + 1;
            System.out.print(i1 + ", ");
            i = i1;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(" ");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting your loop counter. Thus after you are done with the hailstone problem with x=200 you do not start it for x=199 but x=3.

Secondly, you are not trying the values from 1 to 200 but all values less or equal to 200. This includes negative numbers as well. Thus your programm ends in an infinite loop.

My solution would be to introduce an additional integer j that you initialize with the value of i at the start of the for-loop and continue on doing subtractions etc. on that integer j. 
To make the outer for-loop finite I switched the condition to i > 0. With that the loop will stop after you are done with the hailstone problem for x=1.

```
for (int i = 200; i > 0; i--) {
        int j = i
         System.out.print(i + ", ");

         while (j > 4) {

            if (j % 2 == 0) {
               int i1 = j / 2;
               System.out.print(i1 + ", ");
               j = i1;

            }
            else {
               int i1 = j * 3 + 1;
               System.out.print(i1 + ", ");
               j = i1;
            }
         }
         System.out.println(" ");

      }
```